# How to set config output to special folder (LocalApplicationData)?

Tags: c#, wcf, configuration, windows-xp, special-folders

Is there a way to set my app.config for my WCF service so that it outputs to the [LocalApplicationData folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) without having to hardcode anything?

`%LOCALAPPDATA%` does not work in XP, and I need to support XP

I have found that `shell:Local AppData` works, but I am not sure how to put this in an app.config

The next closest I can find is `%APPDATA%`, but I do not believe this is not the same as LocalApplicationData

Worst case, I can (but would prefer not to) use code to do this (using the SpecialFolders directly), but I am not sure how to set this while keeping the rest of the settings configurable?

Comment: I am going to leave this open in case somebody can come up with a better way, but I am going to use WIX to update the config appropriately.

Comment: Actually, I realized that this will be different for each user process, so the above method of setting it at install time will not work.

Comment: I had to use log4net, which allows for more control of logging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to get the information you want using only built-in environment variables. The information is inconsistent from Windows XP to Windows Vista/7, so I think your best option is to update your config file during installation where you can determine the OS and access other Windows APIs.

Comment: Accepting this as all my research points to the impossibility of what I want. So, I had to go to log4net, which allows for a creation of special variables read from code.

Answer (score 2):

You can get it from Environment object.

```
string path;
path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
```

Edit according to comment:

Now i understand. You can create your own environment variables to use as part of path in your config.

CMD:

```
set mylocalapplicationdata="somewhere"
```

or C#:

```
string name = "mylocalapplicationdata";
string value = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(name, value);
```

After this you can use `%mylocalapplicationdata%` like other system variables.

You can set variable for one session (process), user, or machine (for machine you need admin permissions).

More information (MSDN): 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z46c489x.aspx

Alternatively you can use string like this:

```
%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data
```

but this is for windows xp only.

Comment: I need this from the .config file

Comment: I have removed my downvote, but this is not an option for me.